# Where can I store very large strings?

Tags: android

I tried to store a very large string in an XML file but after having to force close Android Studios a few times because it froze, it turned out to be too many bytes to store. Another option might be to store it in the Java files, but I don't think that's a good idea. Where can I store this and how could I paste it without my computer freezing?

Comment: If your computer freezing after paste that string, maybe you should think about splitting it

Comment: text file if they are constants and dont need to change. if you need to update it, database.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How much text are we talking?

Answer (score 2):

I Think your best option is to store them in a **database**

Comment: @Larry lawrence or you can also store in .txt file anywhere in device storage in case you have dynamic string value.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your **text in a simple .txt file** inside **assets/res folder** or in SQLite Database and can access it whenever needed.